# Select Option value id and show other input box in value using javascript & codinator but value is not show

Tags: javascript, php

I am using codinator select id show value other input box but not show any values.please help...

**select Option view page code here**

**working fine**

```
<select  id="tanktype" name="tankno" class="form-control tankno" required >
    <option>Select</option>
     <?php
       $queryw = $this->db->where('vh_rdi',$_SESSION['rdi']);
       $queryw = $this->db->get('vh_stock');
       if ($queryw->num_rows() > 0)  
         {
         foreach ($queryw->result() as $roww)
           {
     ?>                             
    <option value="<?php echo $roww->vh_id; ?>"><?php echo $roww->vh_id; ?></option>
   <?php } } ?>
</select>
```

**Result show view field same page but not show any value**

```
<input   name="vh_stock"  type="text" class="vh_stock" value="">
```

**javaScript code here**

**alert('ajax completed. Response:  '+data) fine but after vh_stock getting value not show**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tanktype').change(function(){
            //Selected value
            var id = $(this).val();
            alert("value in js "+id);

            //Ajax for calling php function
            $.post('<?php echo base_url()."index.php/Mechanical_rdirecived/viewtankstock"; ?>', { dropdownValue: id }, function(data){
                alert('ajax completed. Response:  '+data);//working fine result

                //do after submission operation in DOM
                 $(".vh_stock").val(data.vh_stock); //value is not getting 
                 //$(".id1").val(data.id1);                      
              //}, 'json')
            });
        });
});
    </script>
```

[image]

**controller => Mechanical_rdirecived/viewtankstock**

**working fine**

```
public function viewtankstock()  
{ 

$id = $this->input->post('dropdownValue');
$this->load->model('Model_fuel_rdirecived');
$this->Model_fuel_rdirecived->viewtankstock($id);
```

}

**Model=>Model_fuel_rdirecived->viewtankstock($id);**

**working fine**

```
public function viewtankstock($id) {

$this->db->where('vh_id', $id);  
$query = $this->db->get('vh_stock');
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  
    {
   $data['foreach'] = $query->result();
   $id1 = $data['foreach'][0]->vh_id; 
   $vh_stock = $data['foreach'][0]->vh_stock;
   $arr =array("vh_stock"=>"$vh_stock","id1"=>"$id1");
   print_r($arr);
 echo json_encode($arr);
    }
```

}

Comment: you should `return` data from model, load view in controller and pass data from controller.

Comment: please edit my code and share sir please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
<input   name="vh_stock"  type="text" class="vh_stock">
```

**TO :**

```
<input   name="vh_stock"  type="text" class="vh_stock" value="">
```

Try:

**controller => Mechanical_rdirecived/viewtankstock**

```
public function viewtankstock()  
    { 
     $id = $this->input->post('reg_no');
     $this->load->model('Model_fuel_rdirecived');
     $arr = $this->Model_fuel_rdirecived->viewtankstock($id);
     echo json_encode($arr);
   }
```

**Model=>Model_fuel_rdirecived->viewtankstock($id);**

```
public function viewtankstock($id) {
    $this->db->where('vh_id', $id);  
    $query = $this->db->get('vh_stock');

      if ($query->num_rows() > 0)  
        {
       $data['foreach'] = $query->result();

       $id1 = $data['foreach'][0]->vh_id; 

       $vh_stock = $data['foreach'][0]->vh_stock;

       $arr =array("vh_stock"=>"$vh_stock","id1"=>"$id1");
       return $arr;
        }

}
```

**JavaScript error**

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#tanktype').change(function(){
            var id = $(this).val();
            $.post('<?php echo base_url()."index.php/Mechanical_rdirecived/viewtankstock"; ?>', { dropdownValue: id }, 
            function(data){

                alert('ajax completed. Response:  '+data);//msg=ajax completed. Response:    {"vh_stock":"600","id1":"4"}

                 $(".vh_stock").val(data.vh_stock);//no recived how can no recived  data
                 $(".id1").val(data.id1); //no recived how can no recived  data
              },)
            });
        });

    </script>
```

**result**

```
ajax completed. Response:  undefined
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204148/discussion-on-answer-by-ramki-select-option-value-id-and-show-other-input-box-in).